# jQuery AJAX call with datePicker working everywhere except IE 6, 7

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having a tough time figuring out why this piece of jQuery code isn't working in IE 6 or 7:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#realdate",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#tcontainer").animate({"opacity" : 0}, 500, function() {
                $.post("index.php", {date: $("#realdate").val()}, function(data) {
                    data = $(data).find("#maintable");
                    $("#maintable").html(data);
                    $("#maintable tr:odd").addClass("alt");
                    $(".stripe tr").hover(function() {
                        $(this).addClass("trhover");
                    }, function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("trhover");
                    });
                    $("#tcontainer").animate({"opacity": 1}, 500);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

I've tried changing out the animate() methods with fadeIn/fadeOut and show/hide, and that didn't work. I tried not doing any animation at all, and that didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working in IE 6 and 7? It works everywhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly isnt working? the ajax call?? have you tried fiddler to see whether the call is being made? Do you have any error message?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. The data is being returned (from what I've seen with Firebug and Chrome's inspector and things like that), but it's not "displaying itself" again like it should. No error messages. Haven't tried fiddler, what's that?

Comment: if the data is being returned but not displayed, could be a problem with your css.  the pluralsight jquery videos are free right now... (for the next few hours) check out the ajax chapter... they also show how to use fiddler - http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/Course/Toc.aspx?n=jquery-fundamentals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just like to let everyone know that I solved the problem that was happening with IE 6 and 7 and would like to share the solution with everyone. These were the two lines causing the issue - data = $(data).find("#maintable"); and $("#maintable").html(data); What was happening was I thought I was replacing the new data from the AJAX request into the table while replacing the whole table itself at the same time. What was really happening was the code above was placing #maintable inside of the existing #maintable, so there were really two tables. I had thought that by doing the code above, it would have just overwritten the table that was there along with the new data, but that was not the case. I created a div with an id of adminarea (or something like that) and modified the two lines to look like this:

```
data = $(data).find("#maintable");
$("#adminarea").html(data);
```

I hope that this is helpful to someone out there that may run across the same issue. Thanks again to everyone who helped!